# Cloud ML efficiently read a large number of images from Google Storage

Tags: machine-learning, io, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I want to use Keras to train a model on a dataset of 40 GB of images and I'm trying to make the process of reading those images as efficient as possible.

Downloading them locally is not an option. Does Tensorflow's `file_io.FileIO()` read instantly or does it somehow cache its results?

Is there and alternative to it?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow's GCS file system implementation does have a block level cache that you can configure, but for your use case the recommendation is to preprocess the images as TFRecord files ([random link](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html) from a Google search). Small reads from GCS generally results in bad throughput.

Comment: So as my understanding goes the best solution would be to store the images + labels in a TFRecord file, store that in GCS and read from it. Is that correct? I'm using Keras, but I don't think this poses any problems.

Comment: Correct. I'm not super familiar with Keras, but I believe you should be able to read the files.